# mirror a html section

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-events

I would like to create an html page with a div that will contain the same content as another div. i want that any change in the origin will be reflected in the destination.
Can you please help with:
1 - Which DOM events do I need to listen to?
2 - How do I apply the events to the destination?

I saw these events: DOMAttrModified, DOMNodeInserted, DOMNodeRemoved, DOMSubtreeModified
but I don't know how to parse them.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery has a .clone() function that would be helpful for this.  Check it out [here](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: This means that I will need to clone the div for each change - in an environment with many changes that would be inefficient.